# Cookies in WebView Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I can't read all my cookies, in my webview i can only read "PHP_AUTH_SID" named cookie, but in browser i can see all cookies. Here is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_login);
```

And this is my shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method in web view client

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
final CookieManager cookiesManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookiesManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
final String cookies = cookiesManager.getCookie(COOKIES_HOST);
Log.i("123123", cookies);
```

in LogCat i can see only: "09-13 14:05:48.139: I/123123(21188):PHP_AUTH_SID=..."

in browser:

PHP_AUTH_SID=...,
access_token=...

Comment: how can i get my access_token cookie in webview ?

Comment: are you sure the cookie is supposed to be there ? the browser and web view don't share the same cookie jar

Comment: yes, i'm sure, i found new bug in my logic - i get an error when it's first time login. Next tries are successful. (Only if i don't clear cookies in cookie manager)

Comment: so, the problem was in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method.

Comment: , i got all my cookies in onPageFinished() cause they appeared only if the page was loaded. And shouldOverrideUrlLoading() called before the page started...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the output from LogCat is just cut off. Just try to debug and see the "really" content of "cookies" string.

I think you could just parse the `cookies` string with `String[] elements = cookies.split("=")`

Comment: I saw real result in debug mode. It's only one string "PHP_AUTH_SID"